# Comma flashes then disappears in total reviews

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Where it shows your total review count on the review tab such as [late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers), it flashes the number with a comma for split second. For example, **2,119** before quickly turning into **2119**. This is inconsistent with the [stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) page which always shows the number with a comma in the top right beside your progress bar. I noticed this a while ago but I figured I was being pedantic.

My question: why does the comma disappear on the actual reviewing page but on the stats page it keeps the comma? Can this be made to be consistent?

Screen shot AFTER the comma vanishes on the review tab:

[image: Total on review tab]

Screen shot on the stats tab:

[image: Total on stats tab]

Comment: Probably never intended for it to get that far?

Comment: @0A0D Not true. Suggested edits started with people with over 8,000 reviews. Low quality and close votes also started in the thousands.

Comment: This is why this site is so damn solid. We OCD on virtually every single (sometimes stupid and minor) "bugs". :D

Comment: @AustinHenley: I don't know about that.. I don't have that many reviews

Comment: @0A0D I don't either. Anyone can view it by going to the stats page: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have commas after the next build.  Enjoy!

Comment: Awesome. Can you explain why it disappeared?

Comment: Sure, they were never there for the > 999 case.  We manufactured a few more commas from our comma factory to support this feature.

Comment: Do you make free trade commas or corporate oppression commas?

Comment: Can we have commas in the "Top Reviewers all time" section too? :X